# AngularGrid library produces empty space in some special cases

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-grid

I am using Angular grid to achieve a Pintrest-like fluid layout of items on my page. It works fine in general but in soem special cases it produces an empty space on my page. It seems the position of item7 is not calculated correctly
[image: mockup of what is happening ins ome cases]
I am using AngularGrid from [here](https://github.com/s-yadav/angulargrid)
My code is quite similar to what they recommend in their [documentation](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/angulargrid/#documentation) except that I am not using an image but a custom component inside the ng-repeat.
so it looks like this:

```js
angular.module('app').controller('demo', demo);

function demo($rootScope, $scope, apiService, angularGridInstance) {
    var self=this;
    this.noOfProjects=8;
    this.firstNo=0;

    this.loadedProjects;
    this.totalProjects;

    apiService.searchProjects($rootScope.userId, self.noOfProjects, self.firstNo).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            self.loadedProjects = response.data.matches;
            self.totalProjects  = response.data.header.totalCount;

            console.log(self.loadedProjects);
            $scope.pics=self.loadedProjects;
        });
    
}
```

```css
.dynamic-grid{
            position: relative;
        }
.angular-grid > *{
 opacity: 1;
}
        .dynamic-grid.angular-grid{
            display: block;
        }

        .grid {
            position: absolute;
            list-style: none;
            background: #ffffff;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .grid-img {
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;

            background-color: #fff;
            
        }

        .grid-img.img-loaded{
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<div class="" data-ng-controller="demo">
      <ul class="dynamic-grid" angular-grid="pics" grid-width="300" gutter-size="10" angular-grid-id="gallery" refresh-on-img-load="false" >
          <li data-ng-repeat="project in pics" class="grid" data-ng-clock>
              <project-info-min-grid project="project" class="grid-img" ></project-info-min-grid>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. a bit of research showed that this was actually cased by this css on some parts of the content of each item:

```css
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Instead I am now shortening the string in javascript like this:

```js
var maxLength=100;
            if(self.project.description){
                if(self.project.description.length > maxLength) {
                    self.project.description = self.project.description.substring(0,maxLength-1)+"...";
                }
            }
```

and everything works fine. Just in case someone else runs into this problem...